# Can I pass a method into another method in Java

Tags: java, methods

For example I have the following method call:

```
Requests.sendGet("/type", Model.setTypes);
```

Model.setTypes is a setter for a List of Types,  I want the sendGet method to be able to call whatever method gets passed into it, and no the sendGet method can't just call Model.setTypes itself, because it depends on what type of Get request is being performed.

Thanks to anyone who replies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, although clumsy: You can use `java.lang.reflect.Method` to point to a method and call its `invoke` member to call it.

However, in almost all cases, this is not what you want to do. Instead, use an interface for that (i.e. your function accepts an object of a certain type that implements an interface), or you can take a `Runnable` and call the run() function of it, or a `Callable` and use `call()`.

(Thanks to Crom for pointing out `Callable`)

Comment: Callable might be a better choice than Runnable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I ended up making an interface.  I already had the thought that is what I'd have to end up doing.  But I was hoping for something like a function pointer capability in Java.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

```
public interface Command {
    public void execute();
}
```

---

```
public class Requests {
    public static void sendGet(String url, Command command) {
        // Do your stuff here and then execute the command.
        command.execute();
    }
}
```

---

```
final Model model = getItSomehow(); // Must be declared final.
Requests.sendGet("/type", new Command() {
    public void execute() {
        model.setType();
    }
});
```

You can if necessary add an argument to `execute()` method, like `RequestEvent` which can be created by `Requests#sendGet()` and accessed in `Command#execute()`.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have [first class functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function): that is functions - amongst other things - passable as arguments - [albeit there is a proposal](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t90987.html). Instead this problem is typically solved in Java with [function objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_Java) - usually objects that implement an interface with a single function. An example would be the Collections API [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

So in your situation define an interface (e.g. `ModelSetter`) with a single method (e.g. `setTypes(List list)`). Define `Request.sentGet(ModelSetter modelSetter)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void invokeAMethod(Object o, String methodName, String...params){
    try{
    Class<?> driverClass = o.getClass();
    Method[] driverMethod = driverClass.getMethods();
    for(Method m : driverMethod) {
        if(m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(methodName)) {
            if(m.isVarArgs()) {
                Object[] obj = new Object[params.length];
                for(int i=0;i<params.length;i++) {
                    obj[i] = params[i];
                }
                m.invoke(new Object[]{obj});
            }
            else
                m.invoke(o,params);
        }
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In The above code, parameters are:
Object o: Object of the class in which your calling method belongs
String methodName: name of the method which you want to call.
String...params: parameters of the method which you want to call.

```
public class Sample{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        method2("method1")
    }

    public void method1(){
        System.out.println("method1");
    }

    public static void method2(String methodName){
        invokeAMethod(this,method1);
    }

}
```